# List or identify layers in Photoshop that are svgs with vector data to export

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg, export

I'll try to articulate this question, but feel free to call out vagueness or false assumptions.

Is there a way in Photoshop to list which layers in a psd file *have complex svg information* in them? That is, not layers that will export to svg markup wrapping of a raster ( with an `<image>` tag in it linking to a raster file). But instead, ones that export to be svgs composed of `<path />` or shape markup (`<circle>`, ...),.

My hunch is that only layers that the document creator *already embedded* as svgs will correctly export to full information ones. My goal is to *better identify* and so extract such items in the psd, typically logos or other icon assets for example. These are the assets that stay crisp/sharp at any zoom level. Is there a tell in the layer menu for layers that have such information? Or a handy plugin that lists those layers in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine filtering the Layers Panel for Vector layers and/or Smart object may work.

[image]

**I think you'd have to *manually* check any Smart Object layers** though since they can be either raster or vector. There's no discernible way to tell what a smart object layer contains until you open the smart object. At least none which I'm aware of.